# Creating a thumbnail from UIImage using CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgimageref, cgimagesource

I want to use the function `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` to create a thumbnail from an `UIImage`. All I have is the `UIImage` itself. The image is the snapshot on a `UIView`.

Please, I don't want to use any other method to create the thumbnail, just the one using `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex`, because I want to compare its performance with the other methods I already have.

Said that, this is the code I have so far.

I have create a `UIImage` category with this code:

```
- (UIImage *)createSquaredThumbnailWithWidth:(NSInteger)width {

  CFDictionaryRef options = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) @{
                                                         (id) kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : @YES,
                                                         (id) kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : @YES,
                                                         (id) kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : @(width)
                                                         };

  CGImageRef scaledImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(????, 0, options);


  UIImage* scaled = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scaledImageRef];

  CGImageRelease(scaledImageRef);

  return scaled;
}
```

My problem is with this line:

```
  CGImageRef scaledImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(????, 0, options);
```

The first parameter of this function demands a `CGImageSourceRef`, but like I said, I just have an `UIImage`, that image is on memory, not on disk, and I don't want to save it to disk, or the performance will go down the drain.

How do I get a `CGImageSourceRef` from a `UIImage` that is on memory???

Comment: what about on memory? all image instances are in memory. Use it as @Nirav D said.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which method for creating a thumbnail from a UIImage is the 'best' (in terms of memory usage, time etc)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you try using `CGImageSourceCreateWithData` and passing image data as `CFDataRef` like this:

**Note:** Using `CGImageSourceCreateWithData` loses information about image rotation, use the `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL` for hassle free rotation of final image.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
CFDictionaryRef options = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) @{
                                                     (id) kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : @YES,
                                                     (id) kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : @YES,
                                                     (id) kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : @(width)
                                                     };

CGImageRef scaledImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, options);
CFRelease(src);
UIImage *scaled = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scaledImageRef];
CGImageRelease(scaledImageRef);
return scaled;
```

**Note:** If you have `URL` of image then you can create `CGImageSourceRef` using `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL`.

```
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(imageFileURL), NULL);
```

Comment: Missing `CFRelease(src)`?

Comment: @Pang If you are facing memory leak than try once releasing src object.

Comment: One of the least memory intensive options I've come across. Very useful, thank you.

Comment: After doing CFRelease(src) still facing memory leak

Answer (score 24):

Swift 4 code

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
let options = [
    kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
    kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
    kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 300] as CFDictionary
let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, nil)!
let imageReference = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options)!
let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: imageReference)
```

Comment: This really came handy after series of web search! Thanks for this wonderful solution.

Comment: Also review a post https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/ by mattt where he has listed many image scaling techniques and their performance benchmarks.

Comment: How to make thumbnail image orientation not rotated, i tried by changing kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform to false, but still it is rotating, All i need is whether original image is of portrait or landscape , i dont need thumbnail to be rotated.

Comment: @virtplay you can apply image rotation from original image: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: originalImage.scale, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)

Comment: @Ivan are these line safe to call in main thread or CGImageSourceCreateWithData will create a lag if called in UI thread?.

Comment: @rajneeshbiswal is probably laggy, but it's barely noticeable if the image is small.

Answer (score 15):

> **Swift 5.1 extension**

based on Ivan's answer

```
extension UIImage {

  func getThumbnail() -> UIImage? {

    guard let imageData = self.pngData() else { return nil }

    let options = [
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 300] as CFDictionary

    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil) else { return nil }
    guard let imageReference = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, options) else { return nil }

    return UIImage(cgImage: imageReference)

  }
}
```

Comment: .jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.95) is faster than .pngData() while providing almost the same quality

Answer (score 0):

Swift and **iOS 15**

```
func preparingThumbnail(of size: CGSize) -> UIImage?
```

Example would be:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "info")
image.preparingThumbnail(of size: CFSize(width: 300, height: 400))
```

Comment: how to preserve aspect ratio? current it is not preserving